# Select > Select > Textbox (Category > Item > Item description)

Tags: javascript, select, drop-down-menu, onchange

I am trying to achieve something with 2 select tags and 1 input (text)

I have 1 select tag:     Category
I have 1 select tag:     Item
and I have 1 input tag:  Item description

They should be dynamic so Item description shows only the value from Item, and Item shows only the values from Category. But I already used the value of the 2 select tags to interact how can I let the input tag show responsive text

Here's the example only working for the first 2 select tags. The content of the input should respond to the 2nd select tag.

```
$("#select1").change(function() { 
  if($(this).data('options') == undefined){
    /*Taking an array of all options-2 and kind of embedding it on the select1*/
    $(this).data('options',$('#select2 option').clone());
  } 
  var id = $(this).val();
  var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
  $('#select2').html(options);
}); 

$("#select1").trigger('change');
```

And a fiddle (example) http://jsfiddle.net/hW4Mm/3/

My own document has this:

```
            <select name="select1" id="select1">
                <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
                    echo "<option value='" . $row['id_ziektesoort'] . "'" . ">" .  $row['naam'] . "</option>";
                }
                ?>
            </select>

            <label>Incident: </label>
            <select name="select2" id="select2">
                <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
                    echo "<option value='" . $row['ziektesoort_id_ziektesoort'] . "'" . ">" .  $row['naam'] . "</option>";
                }
                ?>
            </select> 

            <input name="advies" id="advies" type="text" readonly="readonly"><?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)) { 
                echo $row['advies'];
                }?>
            </input>
```

Comment: What do you want to display in the input? (Be responsive is not enough  to say)

Comment: Just a description in text

Comment: Yeah, but where is the description?

Comment: in my own document I am using php (echo) to fill the content. So anything would do for now. Like: 1 > 1a > 1a description .... 2 > 2a > 2a description

Answer (score 0):

You can add another function in javascript that will be callled on change of `select2`. The function below will set the text value of `select2` in the input text box. When you change the value of select2 the its text value will be displayed in the input text box.

```
$("#select2").change(function() { 

     document.getElementById("text").value=$("#select2 :selected").text(); 


    });
```

Also you have to write your input text box as follows:

```
<input type="text" id="text" name="text" value=""></input>
```

Please let me know if you need more details on this.

Fiddle url: http://jsfiddle.net/hW4Mm/18/

Comment: Did you find what you are looking for, or you need something else.